# Uploading files with non-English characters in name to Blobstore in App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, utf-8

I have encountered this problem with the Java runtime which apparently was resolved for Python - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

When the filename contains non-English characters, getting it from either BlobInfo.getFilename() and FileInfo.getFilename() returns a base64-like string (but it's not base64 as far as I could figure) starting with =?UTF-8?

This happens only in production. In the development server I get a string which I can convert to UTF-8 encoding.

I saw that for Python some users were able to overcome this before the official fix. I tried to add accept-charset="utf-8" to the upload form, but it didn't seem to matter. Is there a workaround for this? I thought about using a non-standard way to send the filename (ie. encode it on the client and decode it on the server) but I prefer a cleaner solution.